# Gevent blocked by flask even use monkey patch

Tags: python, flask, gevent, flask-restful, greenlets

I'm using the flask+gevent to build my server, but the gevent named 'getall' was blocked by flask, so the 'getall' function cannot print message in this code. The monkey patch is in use.

```
import time
import WSGICopyBody
from flask import Flask
import gevent

def handle_node_request() :
    while True :
        print 'in handle_node_request'
        gevent.sleep(1)

def getall() :
    print 'in getall'

def create_app() :
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.wsgi_app = WSGICopyBody.WSGICopyBody(app.wsgi_app)
    app.add_url_rule('/node',
                     'handle_node_request',
                     handle_node_request,
                     methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
    return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    from gevent import monkey
    monkey.patch_all()
    gevent.joinall([
            gevent.spawn(app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8899, debug=True)),
            gevent.spawn(getall),
        ])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the function and arguments to `spawn` which will call the function with those arguments in the separate eventlet, but right now you are actually calling `run`, which never ends until you kill it.

```
gevent.spawn(app.run, host='0.0.0.0', port=8899, debug=True)
```

---

On a side note, this does not seem like the right way to run Flask with Gevent.  The [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#gevent) describe using [`WSGIServer`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.pywsgi.html#gevent.pywsgi.WSGIServer).  Additionally, you should use a real app server in production (that is, when you're not running on 'localhost').  [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) and [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) are both capable of using Gevent to handle requests.